# Script tag not loading in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm new to using scripts in HTML, and I'm following a tutorial, where he loads the script after the body (loading reasons).

In my code, I need to put the script in the head section and after the body. If I remove one of them stops working.

```js
$("button").click(() => {
  $("#img1").css("width", "500px");
});
```

```html
<!-- added by editor to correct the relative path to jquery for demo purpose -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- original markup -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>JQuery Selectors</title>
  <script src="../JS/JQ.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../../../JQuery/jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Events in JQuery</h1>

  <img src="../../../Media/word-image-1.png" alt="image" id="img1" width="1000px">
  <button id="btn">Click</button>
</body>
<script src="../JS/JQ.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../JQuery/jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</html>
```

[Video](https://streamable.com/phkb04)

Comment: *"I need to put the script in the head section and after the body"* - No, you need to pick one or the other.  Why do you think you need to execute the same code twice?  When the code fails, have you checked the browser console for errors?

Answer (score 1):

**You need to remove the 2 lines from the header and in the body you should load "../../../JQuery/jq.js" before "../JS/JQ.js".**

Thats probably because in the header you are loading

- your code (which doesnt work because jquery has to be loaded first)
- jquery

and then at the end of the body you are loading

- again your code (which works now because jquery is loaded)
- again jquery which is not needed